# How can I find Log of truncating a table in BIG query?

Tags: logging, google-bigquery

Hope you all are doing good. So there is a situation that in my bigquery DW there is a table named "users", it get's truncated itself after some time. I don't know why is it getting truncated now I want to find out why? How can I do that? I think someone else is truncating it

Tried checking the logging section but I couldn't find anything related to truncate.

Comment: You should be able to look back in the audit trail of the project and see who/what has been changing the table.  You could also use Time travel to look back at earlier versions of the table and determine "how" it is being truncated.  One possibility is that you have configured the table to be partitioned and defined a partition expiration.